# How to localize with BufferedReader?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, reader

In Java 11 BufferedReader [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html) I have found following sentence:

> Programs that use DataInputStreams for textual input can be localized by replacing each DataInputStream with an appropriate BufferedReader.

I cannot find any explanation how it can be done - what would be an **appropriate** buffered reader in this context?

Comment: Just a guess: I looked at [`DataInputStream.readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()) and found that it doesn't convert bytes to characters properly. "Localised" here could just mean "handles Unicode properly". I don't think the word "appropriate" is that important here. It just refers to a buffered reader that reads from the `DataInputStream`

Comment: Please find those links which could help you [Link_1](https://zetcode.com/java/inputstream/), [Link_2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-io-bufferedreader-class-java/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a really bizarre (I'd say broken) use of the term 'localization' here - it's making an obscure (in that it doesn't link to it) reference to `DataInputStream`'s known-broken [`readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()) method, especially considering that this method's javadoc explicitly refers to BufferedReader. I assume that line was added at the same time as the 'can be used to localize' line was added to BR's javadoc.